# Javascript license

Tags: licensing

I am just entering the field of web development and I was wondering if the Javascript language has a license for the development of web applications for commercial purposes or there is a fee to pay for its use (for commercial purposes). I have been looking for information but I am not sure if it is in charge of Mozilla or Ecmascript, I have even read that "Javascript" is a registered trademark of Oracle, but in either case I cannot find anything regarding the license. Could you help me by indicating if the use of this language to develop web applications commercially is free or if you know the license, please indicate it to me?

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/javascript-trap.html) is a good discussion, below citing from this text:

> The JavaScript language itself, as a format, is free, and use of JavaScript in a web site is not necessarily bad. However, as we've seen above, it can be bad—if the JavaScript program is nonfree.

You can use it for commercial web applications, but you have to be careful with libraries which might come with all kind of licenses.

Furthermore from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Trademark):

> "JavaScript" is a trademark of Oracle Corporation in the United States. It is used under license for technology invented and implemented by Netscape Communications and other parties.

That's why you might run into trouble if you use the name, see e.g. [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/56712/what-to-do-if-you-are-sued-for-company-name-that-resemble-an-existing-company-na).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer.